# Run Groovy application

Tags: groovy

Now I need development and run simple Groovy TCP server.
Could you please help me make the right choice how I can run my application?

I know follow methods how I can run my Groovy simple application:

1) I can run:

```
groovy myserver.groovy
```

2) I can create jar-file and run it. In this case I can write follow code (accordingly documentation):

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper

class MyApp extends Script {
    def run() {
        // TODO             
    }

    static void main(String[] args) {
        InvokerHelper.runScript(MyApp, args)
    }
}
```

Please help me, which way is more effective?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simple cases you can run your Groovy script in "listening" mode with the `-l` flag, like this:

```
groovy -l 9010 SimpleServer.groovy
```

This starts the SimpleServer script listening on port 9010. I took this example from mrhaki's Groovy Goodness blog here: http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/12/groovy-goodness-serversocket-scripts.html. Check it out for the complete example.